# Can't invoke public method in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I have following constructor in a public class:

```
public LoginPage(Browser browser, Logger logger) throws GeneralLeanFtException {
    super(browser, logger);
}
```

`browser` and `logger` variables are defined in `BasePage` class, which is extended by this class.

```
public class BasePage {
    protected Browser browser;
    protected Logger logger;

    public BasePage(Browser browser,Logger logger) throws GeneralLeanFtException {
        this.browser = browser;
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

I get following error message when execute it with `TestNG`.

> either make it static or add a no-args constructor to your class

Error stack:

> throws
>   com.hp.lft.sdk.GeneralLeanFtException,java.lang.InterruptedException:
>   either make it static or add a no-args constructor to your class  at
>   org.testng.internal.Utils.checkInstanceOrStatic(Utils.java:795)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:40)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)

Class from test is executed:

```
@Test
public class LeanFTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        testNG.setTestSuites(Arrays.asList("testng.xml"));
        testNG.setPreserveOrder(true);
        testNG.run();
    }

}
```

Comment: You question is not clear. Can you add your test class and error stack?

Comment: @ShaunakPatel : I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

`Protected` variable can be seen by this class, classes in the same package and classes which extend that class.

`static` variable exists at class level, it does not exist separately for each instance and it does not have an independent existence in classes which extend class.

```
 public class BasePage {
        protected static Browser browser;
        protected static Logger logger;

        public BasePage(Browser browser,Logger logger) throws GeneralLeanFtException {
            this.browser = browser;
            this.logger = logger;
        }
    }
```

try like this by making `protected` variables as `protected static`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but looking exception message, and [source code](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/internal/Utils.java#L690) it seems you need to have no argument constructor in your class.

Can you add no argument constructor in your *BasePage* and *LoginPage* class and check?

Comment: Arguments are needed in this case.

Comment: `browser` and `logger` are needed in execution.